# Hook for fail and successful login actions

Tags: login

I need to log **fail** and **successful login** actions.

What hook is better to use for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few different hooks you can use (from [`wp_signon`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)):

- [`wp_authenticate`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/user.php#L41) (action)
- [`authenticate`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/user.php#L51) (filter)
- [`wp_login`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/user.php#L64) (action)

But you may do best to override the [pluggable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) `wp_authenticate` (from `wp-includes/pluggable.php`):

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_authenticate') ) :
/**
 * Checks a user's login information and logs them in if it checks out.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param string $username User's username
 * @param string $password User's password
 * @return WP_Error|WP_User WP_User object if login successful, otherwise WP_Error object.
 */
function wp_authenticate($username, $password) {
    $username = sanitize_user($username);
    $password = trim($password);

    $user = apply_filters('authenticate', null, $username, $password);

    if ( $user == null ) {
        // TODO what should the error message be? (Or would these even happen?)
        // Only needed if all authentication handlers fail to return anything.
        $user = new WP_Error('authentication_failed', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username or incorrect password.'));
    }

    $ignore_codes = array('empty_username', 'empty_password');

    if (is_wp_error($user) && !in_array($user->get_error_code(), $ignore_codes) ) {
        do_action('wp_login_failed', $username);
    }

    return $user;
}
endif;
```

All you would need to do is define your own `wp_authenticate` mimicking the actions and adding a few lines to do your logging. That is assuming you don't already have a function that is overriding it.

And as you can see right in the above code, you could use:

- `wp_login_failed` (action)

Comment: I want to add parameter in url when user login successfully in wordpress....is there any way?

Comment: totels will that custom function get overwritten by wordpress on update? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kenef You don't add it to `wp-includes/pluggable.php` you add that function in your own theme or plugin. If it's in your own theme or your own plugin it will not be overwritten by WordPress on update. You would add that code without the conditional check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use action `wp_login`

Here is the code example

```
function after_login( $user_login, $user) {
    echo "<br/>Username: $user_login";
    echo "<br/>user obj: "; print_r($user);
}
add_action('wp_login', 'after_login', 10, 2);
```